# RegionIntersection of two overlapping lines

Tags: regions

Consider these simple exampes of two overlapping lines:

```
RegionIntersection[Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}], Line[{{1 , 0}, {2, 0}}]]
(*Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}]*)
RegionIntersection[Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}], Line[{{1 , 0}, {3, 0}}]]
(*Line[{{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}}]*)
```

In both examples Mathematica evaluates the intersection as expected. 
Surprisingly in the second example with **extra curly brackets** .

My questions:
What's the reason for this behavior? How to avoid or remove the outer curly brackets?

Thanks

Comment: The second answer is also semantically correct, `Line` can represent a collection of lines. If you want to drop the extra list wrapper you can rewrite this specific case: `Line[{{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}}] /. Line[{l_List}] :> Line[l]` $\rightarrow$ `(* Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}] *)`. This doesn't modify the first result.

Comment: @kirma Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer since I guess it's really a sufficient solution to the task at hand...

The second answer is also semantically correct, `Line` can represent a collection of lines. If you want to drop the extra list wrapper you can rewrite this specific case:

```
Line[{{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}}] /. Line[{l_List}] :> Line[l]
```

> Line[{{1, 0}, {2, 0}}]

This doesn't modify the first result.